# Determine and format different timezones datetime formats

Tags: python

I have defferent timezones locales

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

dates = {
['1 oct. 2021 19:36:45 UTC','ES'],
['2 ott 2021 15:49:16 UTC','IT'],
['1 okt. 2021 01:08:30 UTC','NL'],
['1 Oct 2021 00:05:55 UTC','UK'],
['30.09.2021 22:04:57 UTC','DE'],
['30 sept. 2021 23:32:41 UTC','FR'],
['Oct 18, 2021 11:50:38 AM PDT','US'],
['22 dec. 2021 13:47:40 UTC','SE'],
['27 kwi 2022 02:12:51 UTC','PL']
}

def parse_date_convert(date, fmt=None):
    if fmt is None:
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' # Defaults to : 2022-08-31 07:47:30
    get_date_obj = parse(str(date))
    return str(get_date_obj.strftime(fmt)) 

for date in dates:
    print(f'Before: {date[0]}  After: {parse_date_convert(date[0],date[1])}')
```

How to convert thoose different times to one format which i want? For example to "2022-06-01 00:00:00"

Expected result:

```
Before: 1 oct. 2021 19:36:45 UTC  After: 2021-10-01 19:36:45
Before: 2 ott 2021 15:49:16 UTC  After: 2022-10-02 15:49:16
Before: 1 okt. 2021 01:08:30 UTC  After: 2021-10-01 01:08:30
Before: 1 Oct 2021 00:05:55 UTC  After: 2021-10-01 00:05:55
```

...

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but I gather you asking how to convert date time data with different time zones into standard time data with common time zone?  Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that correct

Comment: It looks like handling timezones would be the easy thing, the first step is to handle random and multilingual date+time format

Comment: **"Expected result"** omits timezones altogether  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: does not care about timezones right now, i need Y m d

Comment: You are trying to make **dates** to be a set of lists. It won't do. List is an unhashable type.

Comment: Did you mean to make `dates` a dictionary (rather than a list)? If not, then it should use brackets instead of curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, the basic problem is to handle the multi-linqual date formats.  I am providing an answer for all but the last case, since 'PL' is not a recognized timezone abbreviation.

```
dates = [
['1 oct. 2021 19:36:45 UTC','ES'],
['2 ott 2021 15:49:16 UTC','IT'],
['1 okt. 2021 01:08:30 UTC','NL'],
['1 Oct 2021 00:05:55 UTC','UK'],
['30.09.2021 22:04:57 UTC','DE'],
['30 sept. 2021 23:32:41 UTC','FR'],
['Oct 18, 2021 11:50:38 AM PDT','US'],
['22 dec. 2021 13:47:40 UTC','SE']
]
```

Note: Dates is modified from your sample data in two ways (1)changed from set_of_lists to list_of_lists, and (2) removed last date string.

```
for date in dates:
    print(f"Before: {date[0]}, \tAfter:  {parser.parse(date[0], tzinfos=date[1], fuzzy=True, dayfirst=True)}")
```

yields:

```
Before: 1 oct. 2021 19:36:45 UTC,   After:  2021-10-01 19:36:45+00:00
Before: 2 ott 2021 15:49:16 UTC,    After:  2021-02-02 15:49:16+00:00
Before: 1 okt. 2021 01:08:30 UTC,   After:  2021-01-02 01:08:30+00:00
Before: 1 Oct 2021 00:05:55 UTC,    After:  2021-10-01 00:05:55+00:00
Before: 30.09.2021 22:04:57 UTC,    After:  2021-09-30 22:04:57+00:00
Before: 30 sept. 2021 23:32:41 UTC,     After:  2021-09-30 23:32:41+00:00
Before: Oct 18, 2021 11:50:38 AM PDT,   After:  2021-10-18 11:50:38
Before: 22 dec. 2021 13:47:40 UTC,  After:  2021-12-22 13:47:40+00:00
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but i think, that this solution gives a wrong result. For example the second date is in italian language and "ott" means "ottobre", the third is in the dutch - "okt" - "oktober". Both mean "october", 10th month. I don't think time zone recognition solves the problem with multilingualism.

Comment: I agree, totally missed the month factor.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: looks like `dateutils.parser.parse` does't support non-English formats.

You misused your own function, `parse_date_convert`. As I see, it takes **output** format as `fmt` argument, but you put **input** format in the printing loop. Do this:

```py
for date in dates:
    print(f'Before: {date[0]}  After: {parse_date_convert(date[0])}') # don't put input format
```

Instead of this:

```py
for date in dates:
    print(f'Before: {date[0]}  After: {parse_date_convert(date[0],date[1])}')
```

Comment: Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, or answer with **your code works**. These issues should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. Please see [How do I handle "it's working" answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348880/7758804). These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32392985)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, the main problem is to correctly interpret the names of the months. I found that, the **parse** function of the dateutil model handles it by the means of the **dateutil.parser.parserinfo.MONTHS** variable and **dateutil.parser.parserinfo.months** function.

The variable **MONTHS** contains possible names of months. As i understand there are only english names and abbreviations of the months there. They are stored in a list of tuples, where the index of the element denotes the month number minus one. Like so:

```
MONTHS=[(Jan,January),(Feb,February)...]
#MONTHS[1] is the second month (02)
```

The function **months** controls the way the search is performed.

As recommended in the documentation for the module, you can create a subclass from **dateutil.parser.parserinfo** "*to configure the language and acceptable values for each parameter*". Both **MONTHS** and **months** can be redefined. Although, i think the creators meant, that you can redefine **MONTHS**, but not **month**. What needs to be done depends on the known information about the given data. I think, the surest way would be to know all possible names of months and their abbreviations and make a sublass, containing the corresponding **MONTHS** list or add the missing names to the existing **MONTHS**.

Example:

```
from dateutil import parser
class Custom_parserinfo(parser.parserinfo):
    MONTHS=parser.parserinfo.MONTHS
    MONTHS[9]+=('ott',)     #add **ott** (October in Italian)
```

If there is some information about the language or country along with the datetime data it can help narrow down the search among the extensive list of **MONTHS**.

You can create **MONTHS** list containing all the names of months known in the world to be more universal. But there will be intersections. Also, as I have found, when it comes to abbreviations of month names, there are discrepancies. In this case, the **month** function can be overwritten to find not only exact matches, but substrings that are part of the month names or are at the beginning of the names.

I have created such a subclass with custom **months** and **MONTHS**, but I am not sure of its reliability. It is also backed up by two csv tables containing names, languages, codes, etc... - I can't be sure about them either. That's why I'm not publishing it here.

P.S. The **dateutil** docs: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html